# Use Polly with EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, polly

I'm looking for inputs and hopefully some sample implementation to use Polly with EF Core 3.1. My AspNetCore application uses Azure SQL with EF and repository pattern. I want to use Polly with RetryAndWait policy for Azure SQL requests beginning with initial connection.
I have read that EF Core 3.1 supports EnableRetryOnFailure execution strategy on DbContext. However, I want to see if I can use Polly instead to be consistent with other areas of my application like webApi calls. May be hook Polly within custom execution strategy of EF.

Here is my sample implementation of repository where i want to use Polly policies:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> : IDisposable
{
    Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> ListAllAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    Task<T> GetByIdAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default, int id);
}
```

```
public class EfSqlGenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    public EfSqlGenericRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        this._dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default, int id)
    {
        // retrieve entity via dbcontext
    }
    public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> ListAllAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // list entities via dbcontext
    }
}
```

```
public class DapperRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
{
    private readonly string _cxn;
    public DapperRepository(string cxn)
    {
        this._cxn = cxn;
    }
    public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default, int id)
    {
        // retrieve entity via IDbConnection & sql query
    }
    public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> ListAllAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // list entities via IDbConnection & sql query
    }
}
```

So in terms of application requirements:

When a SQL (or other known) transient error happens, I need to retry for maximum 6 times but with every attempt I need to wait exponentially before trying it again. And if the error persists even after 6th attempt, I want to break the circuit for the next 25 seconds. Finally, if the failure still exists, degrade gracefully using a fallback.

Comment: I would not recommend that.

Comment: Care to explain why not recommended? Thanks.

Comment: Because there is a lot of logic involved in the built in feature that will be hard to get right with Polly

Comment: @Sam What is the problem with the built-in retry strategy? Why do you want to replace that?

Comment: @PeterCsala the reason I wanted to go that route is consistency and control. With Polly, I can use it in my EF Core repository & Dapper repository alike. I would also use it for http client calls. I need to use circuit breaker policy too besides retry & fallback.

Comment: @Sam I do believe all your mentioned policies should be applied inside your service layer rather than inside the data access layer.  Or could you please extend your question with a concrete example?

Comment: @PeterCsala mentioned policies will be applied in base repository so the clients (service layer) don't have to be aware or worry of them. High level flow of application layers: MVC Controller -> Service layer -> Repository -> Data layer.

Comment: @Sam Then could you please provide a **concrete** example what do you want to handle inside your data access layer via Polly policies?

Comment: @Sam Sorry mate, maybe I was not clear enough. I do understand that you want to decorate your data retrieval operation with resilience policy. What I don't understand is how (and why) do you want to handle a transient failure differently than the EF's built-in retry strategy? So, could you please share under what circumstances do you want to issue retries (what will trigger the policies)? And how do you plain to build the policy (escalation) chain (which policy is the inner and which one is the outer)?

Comment: @PeterCsala sorry about any confusion. I edited my original post if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. You don't need to override the built-in one. You just need to wrap the ToListAsyc or FirstOrDefaultAsync method with the policy chain. The built-in retry is triggered for common SQL exceptions like deadlock victim. If you want you can turn off the built-in one.

Comment: So, if I wrap all my repository methods within polly policy execute(), would that be sufficient? As I don't know when EF establishes the DB connection for the first time hence  I'm not sure if my polly policy will be executed at that time or not. Or I'm too late by then.?

Comment: @Sam EF intentionally abstracts away the underlying connection. It uses a connection pool to communicate with database. From application point of view it does not matter when it issues the first connection attempt. When it fails it might throw `SqlException` or `EntityException`([details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-errors-issues#connection-timeout-expired-errors)). So, your policy should handle these primarily in my opinion.

Comment: @Sam Do you have further questions?

Comment: Thanks @PeterCsala for your inputs. I'll start working on the implementation soon.

Comment: @Sam have you implemented it? Any conclusions?

Comment: @LeszekP I stick to default EF implementation for my case as I didn't receive any favorable comments towards Polly benefits over default EF strategy. Let me know if you think otherwise. Thanks!